# Backbone Sub-Collections & Resources

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out a Collection/Model system that can handle retrieving
data given the context it's asked from, for example:

Available "root" resources:

```
/api/accounts
/api/datacenters
/api/networks
/api/servers
/api/volumes
```

Available "sub" resources:

```
/api/accounts/:id
/api/accounts/:id/datacenters
/api/accounts/:id/datacenters/:id/networks
/api/accounts/:id/datacenters/:id/networks/:id/servers
/api/accounts/:id/datacenters/:id/networks/:id/servers/:id/volumes
/api/accounts/:id/networks
/api/accounts/:id/networks/:id/servers
/api/accounts/:id/networks/:id/servers/:id/volumes
/api/accounts/:id/servers
/api/accounts/:id/servers/:id/volumes
/api/accounts/:id/volumes
```

Then, given the Collection/Model system, I would be able to do things like:

```
// get the first account
var account = AccountCollection.fetch().first()

// get only the datacenters associated to that account
account.get('datacenters')

// get only the servers associated to the first datacenter's first network
account.get('datacenters').first().get('networks').first().get('servers')
```

Not sure if that makes sense, so let me know if I need to clarify anything.

The biggest kicker as to why I want to be able to do this, is that if the
request being made (ie `account.get('datacenters').first().get('networks')`)
hasn't be made (the networks of that datacenter aren't loaded on the client)
that it is made then (or can be `fetch()`d perhaps?)

Any help you can give would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options to fetch that will be translated to querystring params.

For example:

```
// get the first account
var account = AccountCollection.fetch({data: {pagesize: 1, sort: "date_desc"}});
```

Would translate to:

```
/api/accounts?pagesize=1&sort=date_desc
```

It is not quite a fluent DSL but it is expressive and efficient since it only transmits the objects requested rather than filtering post fetch.

**Edit:**

You can lazy load your sub collections and use the same fetch params technique to filter down your list by query string criteria:

```
var Account = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.datacenters = new Datacenters;
    this.datacenters.url = "/api/account/" + this.id + '/datacenters';
  }  
});
```

**Then from an account instance:**

```
account.datacenters.fetch({data: {...}});
```

[Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-nested) on fetching nested models and collections

Comment: Right, that works when I'm filtering on the account, but I would want to be able to do:

    `AccountCollection.fetch().first().get('instances')`

Which would make the following calls:

    `/api/accounts`

and then

    `/api/accounts/:first_id/instances`

And give me back those instances.

Comment: Updated my answer with a lazy load method.  You will need to handle the flow control in your router with promises or callbacks but hopefully this will provide the gist.

Comment: That is MUCH closer, but I'm hoping that I could do some sort of automated type deal where I could define my collections/models similar to https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0229026e5a3c08d7426 and it would in turn figure out how to concatenate the `segment` of each collection/model and make happy.

Comment: Something to keep in mind on the gist that I forgot to mention: The reverse relation isn't nearly as important as the forward one. It's just a thought.